# expectations from Allah

Tags: hadith

Assalam walaikum.as allah has stated in hadith qudsi that "I as my slave thinks of me",we all expect good from Allah and having a bad opinion of Allah is a sin,so why does Allah doesn't do things as we expect from him,i mean all that is good for us,for e.g
if a person expects from Allah that Allah will never harm him,never give him trouble,bless him with all the good things of the world but his wish doesn't get fulfilled,so it means that Allah did against that person's expectations?i mean such type of situations happens to everyone so how does he view his lord?

Comment: maybe that hadith is false

Answer (score 1):

Yes but Allah also tells as that he grants us what is best for us. Sometimes we ask Allah for something and we get it a bit late or we get something else instead. This is because Allah knows what we do not know and He knows what is best for us. Remember that for very hardship we see in this dunya, we will get the reward for it in the Aakhirah if not in the dunya.

This verse "and Allah is to His servant and he thinks of Him" means think good of Allah. If you think of Allah that He is good, He is Meriful, He will be good to you and show you Mercy. And if you think of Allah as bad then He will punish you.

One more thing... you cannot think that you can sin or do anything bad because you think of Allah as good so He won't punish you because that goes against all of the other teachings. If you really thought of Allah as good then you would follow His religion properly as you would know that whatever He forbids will do you harm and whatever He has commanded is of benefit to you.

Answer (score 0):

Allah creates mankind with free will. If you really want to do something, you should put in action. If you expect to happen everything by just wanting it, what is the purpose of showing yourself in action which is in a way to obey Allah's rules?

In a basic way, you can do your actions in Allah's way. Other peoples doings around you doesn't concern you. Because they are responsible with their actions. Their actions may not produce good for them or society, but it's their choice. You want good things, you have done good thing, so you will be rewarded by Allah.

This world is not for rewards or punishments.This world for proving yourself to Allah, you are good servant. You can expect things which may harm you to test your belief or patient. If you pass the test you will be rewarded.